# Odd error with caret function rfe

Tags: r, caret

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1) 
x <- data.frame(runif(10),runif(10))
y <- rnorm(10)
rfeModel <- rfe(x,y,rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs))
```

returns:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "undefined columns selected"

While this code:

```
data(BloodBrain)

x <- scale(bbbDescr[,-nearZeroVar(bbbDescr)])
x <- x[, -findCorrelation(cor(x), .8)]
x <- as.data.frame(x)

lmProfile <- rfe(x, logBBB,rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs))
```

Works fine.  What am I doing wrong in the 1st example? (I get the same error in R 2.14.0 and 2.13.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the `sizes` argument ($\leq 2$ in your example). The default value in `rfe` is `sizes=2^(2:4)`, but you only have two features.

`?rfe`

> Arguments
>
> - ...
> - sizes
>
>   a numeric vector of integers corresponding to the number of
>     features that should be retained